# $H_1(F)$ for an orientable, compact, connected surface

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $F$ be an orientable, compact, connected surface of genus $g$ with $n$ boundary components.

> **Claim.** The first (singular) homology group is $H_1(F)=\bigoplus_{2g+n-1}\mathbb{Z}$.

I know that $H_1(F)$ is isomorphic to the abilianization of its fundamental group. So maybe the theorem of Seifert-van Kampen helps?

Is such an $F$ always of the form like [here](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=67b148-1494445403.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n = 1$ $F$ does retract on a bouquet of circle, hence the claim follows. Now, if $n>1$, use one disk to retract everything on a wedge of circle except little "neighborhood" of every other boundary component, they will also add one more circle to the wedge, i.e add one more copy of $\mathbb Z$ to $H_1(F)$.

Comment: Well, thank you! I would like to ask a few questions about this if you don't mind. 1.) (general question, nothing to do with your answer) I have linked a figure. Why does this figure have genug $g$? Isn't $g$ the number of wholes of $F$ here? 2.) I don't see what happens in your induction step, could you say a few more words please?

Comment: 1) : you can see that gluing a disk or removing a disk is not changing the genus as the genus is the number of handles you add. You can see this way : start from the sphere, add $g$ handles and remove $d$ disks, and you get your surface. For be honest I know knot theorist like to draw surfaces of genus $g$ this way but I was never convinced by this picture. I prefer to see it as a $2g$-gon with face identified. 2) With this vision in mind,  you can assume that the first disk you remove is in the center, and you can retract everything on the boundary. If you have only one disk you will

Comment: (continued) get the wedge. But now, if you remove another disk, by continuity you move this disk such that its boundary touches the common points of the wedge. When you will retract, you will simply add a new circle (a picture might help). I hope it's clear.

Comment: 1) What is an handle in my picture? For me it is the things on the bottom row, hence there are $n-1$ many.

Comment: This is the point : you start with an handle, but using the fact that you deleted a disk you somehow can "convert" every handle into a pair of "strips" (which corresponds to $f_1,f_2, \dots$). But as I said, for me this is simpler to write a surface of genus $g$ like on this picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXWIa.png

Comment: Nice and helpful picture! Anyway it would be better if we can stay at "my" picture since I, i.e. we, will work with this in several other cases. I am convinced that this surface has genus $g$, another than your way to see this is using Euler characteristic. A band has characteristic $-1$. But how does your induction step can be explained with my picture?

Comment: In your picture, induction step would be to put one more strip under the surface, which gives a $\Bbb Z$ summand to $H_1(F)$ (by e.g Mayer-Vietoris).

Comment: Could you point out that Mayer-Vietoris argument?

Comment: Assume you have $2$ disks. There will be one strip $f_{2g+1}$ down the surface. You can take $U$ to be a little neighborhood of the strip and $V$ a neighborhood of the complement. $V$ has the same homotopy type as the surface without the disk removed, and of course $H_1(strip) = \mathbb Z$. Finally, since $U \cap V$ is homeomorphic to a rectangle, it has no homology and Mayer-Vietoris gives $ H_1(U \cup V) \cong H_1(U) \oplus H_1(V)$.

Comment: @leparisien : glad I could help.

Comment: In fact, this is more or less my argument with wedge as homology of a wedge is computed using Mayer-Vietoris.

Comment: I again hava a question on your Mayer-Vietoris argument: You get an exact sequence $0\rightarrow\bigoplus_{2g+n1}\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow H_1(F)\rightarrow H_0(rectangle)=\mathbb{Z}$. Now surely the important map is injective by exactness but why is it surjective?

Comment: I still need your help :)

Comment: This means that the map $\oplus_{2g+n-1} \Bbb Z \to H_1(F)$ is injective. On the other hand, any $1$ cycle can be pushed close to your new disk or outside, we have $\dim H_1(F) \leq 2g + n - 1$ so it's an isomorphism.

Comment: Also, if you still have questions you can simply ask new one. (This is the policy of this website which doesn't like extended discussion much)

Comment: I don't get the point. What is a $1$ cycle and what is the new disk you are talking about? Besides I don't know what the dimension of an abelian group means. Can one go about the connecting homomorphism itself, maybe it is kind of obvious that this is surjective. What is the connecting homomorphism in our case?

Comment: Alright, do you want to answer this question here or should I open a new quenstion?

Comment: Sorry I was still sleepy this morning. Write the sequence for H_0, there are 4 terms which cancels all. So you get an isomorphism $H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B) \cong H_1(A \cup B)$.

Comment: Why does the sequence for $H_0$ cancel? A rectangle is path connected, so its zeroth homology group are the integers. See my last comment 2 days before.

Comment: The end of the sequence is $\dots \to H_0(A \cap B) \to H_0(A) \oplus H_0(B) \to H_0(A \cup B) \to 0$. This implies that $\oplus_{2g + n - 1} \Bbb Z \to H_1(F)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: But how? We have the sequence $\bigoplus_{2g+n-1}\mathbb{Z}\to H_1(F)\to H_0(A \cap B) \to H_0(A) \oplus H_0(B) \to H_0(A \cup B) \to 0$ which is equal to $\bigoplus_{2g+n-1}\mathbb{Z}\to H_1(F)\to \mathbb{Z} \to H_0(A) \oplus H_0(B) \to H_0(F) \to 0$.

Comment: All $H_0$ are $\Bbb Z$ in your case. Please open a new question if this is still not clear for you.

Comment: This is clear to me since $H_0$ counts path components. So we have $\bigoplus_{2g+n-1}\mathbb{Z}\to H_1(F)\to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$. But please say: Why can we conclude that the first map is surjective?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58756/discussion-between-n-h-and-leparisien).

Comment: Ok! Thanks! ...